# OpenSSL OCSP Responder don't start anymore

Tags: debian, openssl

I used OpenSSL OCSP server for about a week and it worked fine.
Today I upgraded the system and after a reboot it failed to start.

Here is the command used to start the service:

```
openssl ocsp -index <index.txt> -port 127.0.0.1:2560 -sha256 -CA <ca-chain.pem> -rkey <ocsp.key.pem> -rsigner <ocsp.cert.pem>
```

Now I get this error:

```
Can't parse "127.0.0.1:2560" as a number
```

If I change to just `-port 2560` I get:

```
Digest must be before -cert or -serial
```

Comment: If someone knows another OCSP responder tell me. I already tried openca ocspd but I did not manage to compile it for Debian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently since version 1.1.x the `-port` option can no longer take something like **host:port**.
To fix my problem, I also had to remove `-sha256`.

See the issue at GitHub: [openssl#3719](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/3719).